# Disable the keyboard in OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, osx-lion

I'd like to disable the keyboard in OS X, programmatically, as my cat tends to walk on it & wreak havoc during the progress. I will use the mouse to enable it again by clicking a small icon in the menu bar.

This can be done by unloading the kext responsable for keyboard input, but that requires root privileges.

Any ideas on how to archive the same results without root?

Comment: unplug the keyboard when you are away from the computer?  :-)  You can also use a screensaver with a really short activation time, and set the screensaver to only unlock the computer if you type in your password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done with a Quartz event tap (see `CGEventTapCreate`).  This would require you to go into the Universal Access preference panel and check "Enable access for assistive devices", but not root privilege.